# HQL IN Clause with Array from DB + JOIN

Tags: hibernate, hql

i have a Table where an ArrayList of prices is saved via Hibernate as a Blob.
Now i will get access to that list via IN clause. Is this possible? All with a JOIN of two tables

i.e. with:

```
SELECT * FROM products as p, prices as pr WHERE pr.id IN p.prices
```

p.prices contains an ArrayList with the id of the prices

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible. If you do wish to do anything like this you should store a string of price_id's as a CLOB (TEXT) and use LIKE '%yourID%' OR LIKE '%anotherId%'. But watch out though, this is ugly and you need to make sure you cater for situations so that looking up id 5 is not matched by id 15.

It sounds like you are taking some shortcuts you should seriously reconsider.